# no bundle for bundleID: (null)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect, game-center

This is absolutely driving me batty. I just can't figure it out.

I created an app in iTunes Connect. I set the Bundle identifier in both Xcode and iTunes Connect to "com.spiritjoe.glasstapmasterchallenge."

I ended up having to change the name in Certificates, Identities, and Profiles to "XC com spiritjoe glasstapmasterchallenge" in order to get it to let me link Game Center in Xcode.

I've looked at every post I could find and I still can't figure it out. It's giving me the no bundle for bundleID error every time it tries to call reportAchievements. Here's the code for updating the achievement.

```
public static func UpdateGameCenter(id: String, progress: Float) {
    if(GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated) {

        let achievement = GKAchievement(identifier: id)

        achievement.percentComplete = Double(progress)

        GKAchievement.reportAchievements([achievement], withCompletionHandler: nil)
    }


}
```

I've spent way more time than I'd like to admit trying to figure this out. Any help you might be able to offer would be greatly appreciated. I have also verified that it's not an issue of typing the achievement name somewhere. I specifically checked one of the times this function was called that id is "grp.CareerPoints1" and one of the achievements in iTunes Connect is "grp.CareerPoints1"

Comment: I am using version 7.3. Some other posts have mentioned something about there being an issue with it. I wonder if I should try loading 7.21.

Comment: I've tried revoking and renewing all of my certificates and provisions. I'm really lost here. I'd hate to use one of my two technical tickets on something like this.